# How to out put data from a Azure Function App to capture as a Tracked value

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that is called on a reoccurrence every few hours. The Function then checks a Storage Container "files to process". In this container, there could be 1,2,3... .csv files. The csv file contains 109 columns and 1 to xxx rows. The Function processes each file one at a time and does a bunch of validation. On 1. the CSV is properly formatted ie a correct number of columns, correct Column headers, and correct Data Types. If the Sheet is valid then I process each row. What I need to do is output col 4 (sitloc) and 8  (WO) and col 2 (siteid) to the tracked property so We can search by sitloc and Wo and SiteID. as I loop through the rows how can I output the three fields or even a concat. value? I have no samples, as I have no clue where to start. My Azure function is working as expected and is ver fast in processing the files.

Comment: you need two triggers, the timer trigger to support the reoccurence then output it to a data store, like Azure Storage Table, then you can use a signalr function to call the data from the store and push the information, or a http funtion for the to get the data, which are triggered by an insert to the storage table.